# Changeset items diff between changeset and org

Tags: validation, change-set

Before the new deployment status page was added, there used to be a feature which showed you the items in your changeset that are new, that will modify the existing items, or that have not changed when you validated a changeset. This feature now appears to be missing, but i cannot find a reference in the summer 14 release notes explaining why it was removed. I was wondering what happened to that feature and if it is planned to readd something like it?

Comment: I'm w/ Will on this one.  Previously, when you would Validate an Inbound Change Set, you'd see a list of components, in three groups:  New, Modified, and Unchanged.

It was a very helpful screen that always got a quick visual inspection to see what was being overwritten before the actual deploy.

Is it gone or hiding (very well) somewhere?